# Very different content of an answer in Review and on the actual question's page

Tags: support, review-audits, first-post-review

I decided today to maybe sort out the first posts queue a bit, and the first answer that was presented to me was a one-liner, supposedly made three hours ago. The technology of the question is not familiar to me, so out of curiosity and to get some context, I checked out the actual question's page, to see the other answers. To my surprise, the answer that I was supposed to review was *not* among the given answers, and the person who made it posted a rather reasonably-looking fix. The original "answer" is present, but as a comment under the question. Moreover, the answer and the comment were both made in the end of January, not "three hours ago".

I'm throroughly confused by this. Is this a bug? Is this a quirk of the reviewers' attention checking mechanism?

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388104/core-addproviders-is-not-a-function/54404541#54404541) the answer, and here's how I could see it in the review:
[image: in the review]

Comment: Good for you! You were paying attention, and thus passed the audit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This was a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work). The answer that's shown in review is in fact deleted, by a moderator:

[image: Answer deleted by moderator]

The confusion comes because you, not having the privilege to see deleted posts, can't see that when you visit the page, and the user has *another* answer which *is* visible to you.

If you compare the review answer's ID (from the "link" link on the right of the review page) with the ID of the answer you can see, you'll notice that they are different.

Comment: Are you nominating yourself for moderator? Hint, hint.

Comment: I've been giving it some thought, @CodyGray, but I'm not sure it's in the cards. I appreciate the nudge, though!

Comment: Well, you have another week to shuffle up and re-deal. I'd love to have you on the team, and I know the others would, too. You would definitely be my top choice, for reasons other than we typically see eye-to-eye on moderation issues. It may even rekindle your passion for the site. At least, it helped a lot for me, knowing that I have the ability to be the change that I seek, however silly that seems.

Comment: Heh. Yvette [elbowed me (deleted comments)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380575/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator/380577#comment673283_380577) the other day, too. Flattering. I promise to consider it more. And I'm glad to hear that mod-ship is working like that for you! That's helpful to know, too.

Comment: Something something [you have my axe](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11#post-55056887).