# Deletion of a valid answer by a mod

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderation, specific-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227393/336527) was deleted by moderators, I believe by mistake. While it's short, it absolutely perfectly answers the question. The question currently has no other answers.

Related to this: I think deleting answers should be done more carefully. In this case, the author who put significant effort to answer the question (they actually opened an SO account just for that!), didn't even get a chance to edit their question, they simply saw their answer gone within 3 hours after posting it.

And of course the OP who asked the question, and a couple people (other than me) who upvoted that question, didn't get a chance to see the perfect answer to the question (the OP doesn't have 10k rep). Overall, a very sad outcome.

Screenshot of the answer below. I'm told it's ok to post it.

[image]

Please note that the OP didn't ask for a complicated implementation; they clearly preferred a simple/official way to achieve their goal. So the perfect answer would be a reference to the package/module/class that does what they want. That reference was provided in plain text and in a URL link.

What else should be added to this answer to make it acceptable? I've  been on SO for almost 10 years, and still wouldn't know how to improve this answer. For the person who went to the trouble of answering, this was the first post, so it's even harder for them to see what they did wrong.

The only thing I would think of adding is an example of usage, but it won't solve the problem that if the package is renamed or gone, the answer will no longer be useful. I think that's just the nature of questions about how to do something with an existing API.

Comment: I don't see how this deletion is problematic. The question asks how do perform a certain technique with TensorFlow, the answer is just "use this module" + a link. That is very unlikely to stand by itself.

Comment: That kind of answer might decided as "link-only answer", which may be useless if the link has been stripped out from the post. You should include little bit of details which explained inside the link and provide link just for further reading.

Comment: Sure, but shouldn't the person who answered it be given a chance to update the answer? The answer was deleted within less than 3 hours.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  It's not link-only. It has, in plain text, the name of the package and module. Package/ module can change of course, but what else do you expect someone to say? Copy/paste implementation? The OP clearly preferred an official way to do it, so copying the code wouldn't be the right thing to do.

Comment: Clearly, this amazingly disrupting answer to an otherwise unanswered question needed to be nuked from orbit as quickly as possible to protect the innocent. No need to let votes do the talking first.

Comment: I  really don't understand your definition of "perfect". This answer is not off-topic, yes, but it is neither perfect nor even good. It is slightly above low quality. That you don't see how to improve this answer is really strange. The obvious answer for that is: implementation example. The comment under the answer even mentions that as well.

Comment: @Tom Just to double check, by "implementation example" I assume you mean how to call the API provided in tf.contrib.stateless, so something like `tf.random.stateless_normal([2, 2], seed=42)`?

If so, I'm puzzled why you think it's valuable. The hard part was finding that the package exists; using it is absolutely trivial. There's an unfortunate risk that the package may be gone one day, thus making the answer useless; but that risk seems unavoidable regardless of any changes to the answer.

Comment: I'm also puzzled by the statement "absolutely perfectly". I'm also puzzled why do you think the exampl wouldn't be valuable. The purpose of the question is to be useful to a broad public. If that link doesn't work anymore, the answer will become completely useless. It is a link-only answer and as such discouraged. The criteria for that are clear. The answer must stand on its own. Deleting the answer within few hours is another issue that can be discussed, but the quality of the answer is undisputable, it is indeed low.

Comment: '*The answer must stand on its own.*' - This answer does, maybe the link may or may not become useless but the answer clearly states which module the OP needs to use to solve their problem thus answering the question. It *is* an answer, maybe VLQ (to some) but it should be voted on, not deleted. '*Deleting the answer within few hours is another issue that can be discussed, but the quality of the answer is undisputable, it is indeed low.*' - and it has been the practice to vote on low-quality posts, not outright delete them.

Comment: @Script47 Thank you for agreeing with me. Deleting is highly questionable, the quality is indisputable low.

Comment: @cezar I'm not agreeing, let's not conflate quality with quantity. The answer provides *what* the OP needs to do to solve the problem and *where* to look to solve the problem.

Comment: I deleted the answer because it was a link to a tool/module as an answer, along with the name of it. It was discussed on meta earlier that linking to modules should demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself. The question has a clear requirement. If the answer provided even a small description of how to do it, rather than just pointing to the module, then I would not have deleted it. Also  regarding your flag on that question asking the same, another moderator declined it stating the same reason as mine.

Comment: @BhargavRao Actually, current guidance from Shog9 on Meta.SE says that answers that are "little more than a link" but that contain the name of a tool are [*not* flaggable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/336163). Are you saying that we should start flagging "use tool x" answers as NAA or VLQ?

Comment: The bottom line here is: if you can't be arsed to write more than a single sentence and then drop a link, yet post it as an answer instead of a comment, then expect bad things to happen to that answer. There is just no way this answer could be valuable to the site. If deleted, no loss. Move on with your lives, there's no need to start another crap-hugger debate hurling TLA's around. NAA or VLQ? Who cares, it is a POS answer.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I can't exactly read a statement that broad from Shog's post tbh. The example for the `FileOutputStream` seems to refer to some language feature, for instance. For link-to-tool answers, we've had different, more detailed discussions, for example [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251602/3002139) (already linked by Bhargav) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354501/3002139) (answered by Shog). Now if / how those discussions apply to the answer in question, I'll leave to actual answers.

Comment: How can an answer go from 0 to -1 while it is deleted?

Comment: @KevinB do mods / 10K+ have the ability to down-vote an answer post deletion?

Comment: 10k users can't

Comment: @KevinB the question is rather how an answer can go from -1 to 0 while it is deleted. The downvote was casted on Jan 17, the same day as the deletion.

Comment: Similar case from last month [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380575/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-a-moderator).

Comment: The ***V*** in ***V***LQ seems to be left out quite a bit.

Comment: "_In this case, the author who put significant effort to answer the question (they actually opened an SO account just for that!)_" Except that the answerer registered in October, that's more than two months of foresight in order to answer a question in January! More importantly, I don't see "significant effort" with a single sentence and a link. I guess we use very different [p-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance).

Comment: Given that the answer was "correct", but of "low quality", why did the person who flagged the answer not edit it to improve it?  Why did the moderator not edit the answer to improve it?

Comment: *why did this OP not edit it and flag for undeletion..., why did OP who posted it not edit, why is my wife calling me to clean up the dishes..*

Comment: OP of the question here.  The question answered my exact problem.  I don't know why so much hate for that answer. Thanks @max for flagging this.

Comment: Also someone edited title of my question to be something totally different and irrelevant to the question. I edited the title back to match the question.

Comment: @Pekka In fact there is not much hate for the answer, it is mere individuals that saw it upon themselves to get it deleted.

Comment: @Gimby There's a lot of hate, sadly. The answer that was undeleted immediately got -3 (0 upvotes, 3 downvotes), within minutes of being undeleted. If this is not hate, when people downvote a useful answer, I don't know what is.

Comment: @max It's content rating. Most people here have actually agreed that the answer was low quality.

Comment: @E_net4 no, votes are for usefulness. Flags are for content problems. The only thing that tries to identify quality is a specific flag.

Comment: @Braiam lack of usefulness/clarity is just about what I mean with "having low quality". I don't see your point here.

Comment: @E_net4 it's a specific distinction. For me, votes usually reflect popularity rather than usefulness. A post can be both useful and have content issues, just because some users find a post useful.

Comment: @E_net4: "Most people here have actually agreed that the answer was low quality": the person who asked the question thinks the answer is good. I had the same question, and I think the answer is good. People who didn't have that question, but have a devotion to fight against short answers, intentionally go to the post to downvote the answer. This religious fervor is not cool, IMHO - but obviously I'm in the minority.

Comment: @max Enumerating people who claim in words that were question is useful is missing the forest for the trees. Questions and answers are meant to be useful to future visitors. As such, our users should strive to make their content _as good as it can be_. I can understand why would want it undeleted, but I still can't understand why you consent with having the answer in such a poor state.

Comment: This answer has been deleted a few seconds ago.

Comment: I moved it to the comments below the question.  Nothing more to see here.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is nothing more but a mere link to the official manual for this library. Essentially it says: documentation about TensorFlow can be found in the TensorFlow manual, aka "RTFM".

There is just *no way* that such an answer can be valuable or that we need to preserve it. The mod who deleted it originally did so correctly.

That it has now not only been undeleted but also gotten 7 up-votes(!) is *pathetic*. It makes it blatantly clear that way too many "meta people" have completely lost touch with what Stack Overflow is about.

- Stack Overflow is about quality programming Q&A.
- Stack Overflow is not about lawyering: "NAA VLQ policy Shog said blabla meta meta meta"

I prompted the OP to flesh out an answer themselves and accept it, since they had already done this with an edit to the question. They have now done so: the question is fixed, it is a good answer, it is accepted and it answers the question.

Thus we can now safely delete [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227393/584518) as it now doubtlessly has zero value to the programming Q&A site.

Voting to delete.

Comment: I was very close to answering this question myself, but this seems to cover my major point: "Stack Overflow is not about lawyering". I'll just emphasize that we have wasted too much time and pacience over this petty matter, and this makes a fine example in which [Meta has functioned more to our detriment than in our favour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381212/1233251).

Comment: It takes some serious mental gymnastics to go from "The tf.contrib.stateless module exists for exactly this purpose: <link to docs for module>" to "documentation about TensorFlow can be found in the TensorFlow manual". The former contains information about what you need, the latter does not. Remove the link from the answer and it still contains useful information. Could it be made more useful? Of course! But it's not completely useless.

Comment: @Stijn "But it's not completely useless." That's good news for a site which pretends to be about quality Q&A, isn't it?

Comment: @Tom please, let's not pretend this site is still about **quality** Q&A.

Comment: @Stijn We don't need to, I know times have changed. But regarding this topic: I agree with Lundin that 7 upvotes is very bad for such an answer, especially since several (or most) votes aren't due to the quality of the post, but due to "political" reasons because of this meta question. This tactical voting is pathetic (on both sites).

Comment: "Essentially it says: documentation about TensorFlow can be found in the TensorFlow manual, aka "RTFM": this is incorrect. Neither me nor the OP (who both had the same question) knew if an API existed do what we wanted, and if so, where it was. That's why all we needed is an answer that showed a link to that API (=class/package).

Comment: Meta can get so caught up in the "rights and wrongs" of actions, they forget the site is to provide quality content. A link to a place in the docs is not quality content. Otherwise most of the answers would be "hey go read this."

Answer (score 14):

First, let's start by saying that the answer was flagged as "very low quality" by a non-moderator user first, and also downvoted.

The moderator who handled the flag deleted it probably because he just saw a line of text and a link.

Without being a tensorflow expert, it's very difficult to figure out that this answer has value. We handle a lot of flags and this kind of answer is seen as link-only / software recommendation (and most of the time it *is* exactly that). Such answers are deleted all the time in the VLQ/NAA queue by non-moderators.

The answerer should have used OP input data (present in the question) to show an example of the module in OP context, adding "flesh" to the answer. A comment came in a few minutes after the answer to remind that.

What we saw is lack of experience of the person who answered, who didn't check the messages a few hours after posting, which would have given them the chance to improve the post before the deletion. It happens. But we cannot "spare" a bad answer just because it's the answerer first post.

Now, it's perfectly fine if someone (including original answerer, who could also edit & flag for undeletion) posts another answer with the same link and some code matching OP needs. That would be closer to "the perfect answer". In the meanwhile, I have created a comment with the deleted answer contents & the link as someone suggested in comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190917/discussion-on-answer-by-jean-francois-fabre-deletion-of-a-valid-answer-by-a-mod).

Comment: Someone posting an answer that you think is better than another answer is, again, not a valid reason to delete an answer, so no, it *can't* be deleted just because someone posted another answer.

Comment: I didn't delete the comments, I moved them to chat because it was becoming ludicrious & unreadable.

Comment: @Servy: Look here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190917/discussion-on-answer-by-jean-francois-fabre-deletion-of-a-valid-answer-by-a-mod

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I know they're in a chatroom.  That's why I said they were being hidden.  The *comments* were deleted, and a chatroom was created with the content.  It was done precisely to make it harder to find that content and so that people wouldn't read it.  That the content still exists in a chatroom that people won't read is just a cop out to the attempt to avoid actually addressing the valid criticism of this answer.

Comment: @Servy You know how this works. If you want to express your views, then *post an answer*. Your arguments were *already* hidden in a sea of nearly 100 comments.

Comment: @CodyGray Posting an answer isn't the place to comment on the correctness of another answer.  Comments are the place to comment on another answer.  Posting an answer just to respond to another answer is grounds for deleting that answer as Not An Answer (unlike a moderating thinking it's not a useful answer, as this post claims).

Comment: @Servy It is when you're on opposite sides of the question being asked. If your position is that the answer should not have been deleted by a moderator, then that would be a valid answer to this question.

Comment: @CodyGray Me saying that moderators are not permitted to delete answers just because they're not useful doesn't answer the question asked. I was responding to the direct statements in this answer, and the comments posted on it.  That's what comments are for.  Trying to obscure that criticism, rather than addressing it in any way, or making unresonable demands by claiming responses to another answer that don't answer the question be posted as an answer (that would actually merit deletion) on the grounds that people wouldn't see it (despite dozens of people upvoting them)...